# OpenVPN Block Server Traffic on Client Side

Tags: openvpn, docker, ufw

I'm trying to make a Reverse proxy running OpenVPN Server to expose some ports on a client to the internet. I only want to give the Reverse Proxy access to a webserver hosted in docker at this stage just incase the reverse proxy becomes compromised.

server.conf (reverse proxy)

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "route add 10.8.0.0/24 10.8.0.1"
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert a.crt
key a.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status openvpn.log
verb 3
```

client.conf

```
client
proto udp
remote xxx.xx.xxx.xxx 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name a name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
verb 3
```

docker-compose

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp:
    restart: always
    image: app:latest
    ports:
    - "80:80"
```

The server can access this web server no issue

```
~$ wget 10.8.0.2
--2018-05-07 13:20:55--  http://10.8.0.2/
Connecting to 10.8.0.2:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html' 
2018-05-07 13:20:57 (87.0 KB/s) - 'index.html' saved [134302]
```

So then I tried blocking it use ufw

```
~$ sudo ufw deny in on tun0 to any port 80
~$ sudo ufw deny out on tun0 to any port 80
~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24            
80 on tun0                 DENY IN     Anywhere
80                         DENY OUT    Anywhere on tun0
```

But the server is somehow getting around these firewall rules and can access the web server!

I'm thinking it might be docker because I can see it has added many rules in iptables.

Lastly if this is a stupid / wrong thing thats fair too but please let me know why and what I should do instead

EDIT:

I've found that playing with my docker config produces different results

this stops wget from working

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp:
    restart: always
    image: app:latest
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

this allows it again and it still goes straight thru my firewall above

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp:
    restart: always
    image: app:latest
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
    - "10.8.0.2:80:80"
```

so its obvious docker binding to 0.0.0.0 is doing something. But I still dont know how to fix this without modifying every one of my docker configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution I've come to is that in docker when you bind to port 80 it binds to 0.0.0.0 which includes tun0. Docker modifies the iptable rules dynamically when you create a container and these rules take priority over your ufw rules.

To get around this bind ports to networks which should see your webserver only.

In my case I bound to 127.0.0.1:80 (loopback) and then my server was not accessible on tun0. If you need it to be accessible on a specific network you can just add it e.g. 192.168.1.10:80 (local network)

I read that you can modify the default ip in the /etc/docker/daemon.json file but I attempted this and it didnt work. If it did work you could stop 0.0.0.0 from being the default ip potentially.